# Why do my bytes appear to get corrupted when I try to write them from inside if statements or pattern matches

Tags: scala, byte, scala-compiler

I'm playing with Pickled Scala signatures, writing bytes to a [PickleBuffer](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.10.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/pickling/PickleBuffer.scala) and reading them back out with [ShowPickled](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.10.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/util/ShowPickled.scala).

I can write and read back an `Int` as expected by using

`PB.myBuf.writeByte(2)`

giving the '2' (a reference to an entry number in this case) in

`1(MyRecord) 2 40[case] 5`.

But if I but that same code inside a conditional like:

`if (ExtModClassRef.position==0) PB.myBuf.writeByte(2)`,

or

`ExtModClassRef.position match {case 0 => PB.myBuf.writeByte(2)}`,

then the bytes that I read back are garbled:

`0,4: CLASSsym 4: 1(MyRecordmodels\00\00`...

instead of how the first few entries should be:

`0,4: CLASSsym 4: 1(MyRecord) 2 40[case] 5
1,10: TYPEname 8: MyRecord
2,20: EXTMODCLASSref 1: 3(models)
3,23: TERMname 6: models`

I'm puzzled as to how the `if` and `match` keywords could have any effect on what bytes are written.

And perhaps someone can suggest a fix or a workaround?

Thank you,
Julian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only two ways I can see to influence what bytes are written are:

1. `ExtModClassRef.position` actually isn't `0`, so the bytes you expect to be written aren't, and when you write something else later, it corrupts the record.
2. `ExtModClassRef.position` call modifies `myBuf` in some way.

It's impossible to determine which is the case (or perhaps something different) without seeing your own code.

Comment: Whoops, it was #2.  I had thought that I could just "peek" at the object's member without instantiate it.  Solved by encapsulating some of the objects code in `def`.  Thanks very, very much for taking the time -Julian

Comment: Ha, also +1. I also thought side-effect, but I couldn't take the time, so +1 for taking the time, as @JulianPeeters says.